# Oh Cone-ada! Ice Cream

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Does "ada" have a specific meaning in "[Oh Cone-ada! Ice Cream - Ben & Jerry's](https://www.benandjerrys.ca/en/flavours/oh-cone-ada-ice-cream)" Vanilla Ice Cream with Fudge-Covered Waffle Cone Pieces & Caramel Swirls?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

"ada" has no specific meaning. The name "Oh Cone-ada!" is a play on the national anthem of Canada, "[O Canada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O_Canada)." You'll note that the website you're linking to has a `*.CA` domain suffix, meaning it's [related to Canada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ca). My conclusion is that Ben & Jerry's Ice Cream is marketing the product to Canadians.

Note that it's not uncommon when creating wordplays such as this to use a hyphen to separate the modified component ("cone") from the unmodified original component ("ada").

Comment: Note also the Canadian flag on the tub.

Comment: There appears to be a circumflex accent over the "O" in "Oh" in the photo in OP's link for some reason.

Comment: They also have a flavor called “Americone Dream.”

Comment: @pacoverflow oddly that seems to only be there on their website, if you search for other images of the packaging it's just a plain O

Comment: Lots of B&J ice cream flavor names are wordplay like this. E.g. Cherry Garcia is a pun on the musician Jerry Garcia.

Comment: @pacoverflow: The national anthem is *Ô Canada* in French.

Comment: @Davislor Though that was more of a cross-promotion with Stephen Colbert (in his old show where he played a hyper-patriotic, red-blooded 'Merican, not the current one where he's just himself), rather than a reference to America itself.

Comment: @Davislor:  If I'm not mistaken, "Ôh Cone-ada!" (mentioned by the OP) is the same ice cream as "Americone Dream", just with a different brand name for the Canadian market.  Both are described as "Vanilla Ice Cream with Fudge-Covered Waffle Cone Pieces & Caramel Swirls".

Comment: @DarrelHoffman But he still has an Americone Dream Foundation and occasionally promotes it on The Late Show. Thus demonstrating that patriotism isn't restricted to conservatives.

Comment: @Barmar It’s for anyone who can make a buck or two off it?

Comment: Thank you all for your detailed explanations!